# Application server use for non-web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am interested in understanding "best practice" for the use of application server (for example Glassfish).  I have a medium size application that consists of various components that consume and source web services.  These components are hosted in a Glassfish environment.

I now have a requirement for a simple scheduled function that copies data from one database to another.  That is, it requires no web type functionality.  It could easily be built as a simple application (say around Quartz) and deployed in the same Glassfish server with the other components.  I understand that this is a simple question, however is this a "reasonable" approach or should it really be a stand alone application running independently from an application server?  I guess the more general question is "What are appropriate uses for an application server and what are not?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could just be a shell script called from cron...

Seriously, not a very good use of an app server *UNLESS* you're going to get some sort of monitoring or load distribution out of it. But it sounds like this is really just a batch job in which case you should do the easy thing and just write a script or a simple app with a main method that you either call from cron (or something similar) or run from the command line with some sort of embedded timer (or a sleeping thread).

Comment: Ok - this sounds reasonable.  I guess I was thinking that loading all the components for a specific application into an application server at least keeps them together and allows them to be deployed as a complete "package" - say EAR

Comment: If you have dependencies on your application code that you need to keep in sync with the job, like maybe some domain objects then yes. But even then you could use your build system to keep those in sync. Otherwise it's a lot simpler to just use a shell script solution.

Comment: In part I was thinking of domain objects - yes.  But that is another question - keeping domain objects in-sync across multiple applications and application components....

Comment: the only issue is that using core java, you cant take advantage of features such as initial contexts to inject dependencies like jdbc datasource. you'd need java ee for that.